# Total Multiplicity of Einstein Solids

Tags: thermodynamics

I am reading Problem 2.8 in Schroeder's Introduction to Thermal Physics. The question asks for certain pieces of information regarding two einstein solids, A and B, each containing 10 oscillators, sharing a total of 20 units of energy.

Part (b) asks for the total microstates in this system. Now, when we were looking for the total microstates in a set of fair coins, we can use 2^(# of coins). Is there an equation like this for the system of two einstein solids? If not, then I suspect that the only way to determine the total number of microstates is to find the microstates for each macrostate and then add them up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When looking at the multiplicity of an Einstein solid, the equation tells us the ways of storing the energy across all n oscillators, n-1 oscillators, all the way down to 1 oscillator.  So, if we look at n = all oscillators, we are given the total multiplicity of the Einstein solid.